# Fixed Length Field Export from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How do I go about exporting SQL Server 2005 tables to a fixed length field text file, with one record per line?  SQL seems to think fixed length is the only way to delimit records, i.e. fieldLen1 + fieldLen2 + ... + fieldLenN = recLen.  I can't find any way of delimiting each record with a newline.

Also, when I tried the wizard from a normal DB engine connection, it puked on a column name called "ShortLocation".  I fail to see what could be difficult about writing that out to a text file, but I gave up on the wizard and am trying a SSIS package, but as soon as I make the format "Fixed Width" I lose the row delimiter option.

Surely my requirement is not that unheard of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the 'ragged right' option mentioned here :

http://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/archive/2008/01/31/ssis-flat-file-export-quot-fixed-width-quot-vs-quot-ragged-right-quot.aspx